# what does "trace_module_put/trace_module_get" implement?

Tags: c, linux, kernel

I'm reading Linux kernel 3.12.When I read about i2c_put_adapter in driver/i2c/i2c-core.c,I'm confused.Function "i2c_put_adapter" calls module_put in kernel/module.c ,then module_put called "trace_module_put".But after search all the source code,I cannot find this function and "trace_module_get" ether. While I think this function maybe generated in compile stage.

Could anybody help me get the real meaning of these two funcitons.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

trace_* are macros used by tracepoint which is one static trace utility. you can explore trace point starting from "include/trace/events/module.h" as you are looking for how trace_module_put is 'implemented'

Documentation/trace/tracepoints.txt is the kernel doc for tracepoints.